# how to check if which collectionview is scrolled in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I'm developing app which contains 3 UICollectionViews in one ViewController.
I can know if UICollectionView is scrolled or not with this code

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let isScrolling: Bool = colView.isDragging || colView.isDecelerating
}
```

Specifically I want to know if which UICollectionView did scroll in scrollViewDidEndDragging.

But the problem is that I can't know if which collectionview is scrolled before.
Like I want to know if colview2 is scrolling or not.
Is there anybody who knows this solution? I searched solution on Google and Stackoverflow but I don't think there's such a solution for this problem.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: u can try scrollview delegate methods willScroll/didScroll

Comment: sorry but i don't think that will help

Comment: @MobileStar check if scrollView == yourCollectionView , perform the action. Add this check in scrollViewDidEndDragging , it may give you the desired results as collection view is child class of uiscrollview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Do it by set tag to CollectionView And Scroll View Delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` Here is the Code :

1. First Set tag top your CollectionView in your `ViewDidLoad` method :

```
firstCollectionView.tag = 1 
secondCollectionView.tag = 2 
thirdCollectionView.tag = 3
```

2.Create three Property Observer variable like this upside of your `viewDidload`:

```
   var whichCollectionViewScrolled = "" {
        willSet{
            print(newValue)
        }
    }

    var isFirstCollectionViewScrolled = false {
        willSet{
            print("First CollectionView Scrolled : \(newValue)")
        }
    }
    var isSecondCollectionViewScrolled = false {
        willSet{
            print("Second CollectionView Scrolled : \(newValue)")
        }
    }
    var isthirdCollectionViewScrolled = false {
        willSet{
            print("Third CollectionView Scrolled : \(newValue)")
        }
    }
```

1.lastly inside of your `scrollViewDelegate` method cast your scrollview instance and check the tag value like this :

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if let collectionView = scrollView as? UICollectionView {
            switch collectionView.tag {
            case 1:
                whichCollectionViewScrolled = "First"
                isFirstCollectionViewScrolled = true
                isSecondCollectionViewScrolled = false
                isthirdCollectionViewScrolled = false
            case 2:
                whichCollectionViewScrolled = "second"
                isFirstCollectionViewScrolled = false
                isSecondCollectionViewScrolled = true
                isthirdCollectionViewScrolled = false
            case 3:
                whichCollectionViewScrolled = "Third"
                isFirstCollectionViewScrolled = false
                isSecondCollectionViewScrolled = false
                isthirdCollectionViewScrolled = true
            default:
                whichCollectionViewScrolled = "unknown"
            }

        } else{
            print("cant cast")
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help You .

Comment: sorry but can you please be more specific?

Comment: where you want to know is it scrolling or not ?

Comment: updated my answer is it helping in this situation ?

Comment: the problem is that wih isDragging and isDecelerating value, sometimes there's a bug, like let's say i scrolled col2view, and then after that i scrolled col1view, then co2view's isDragging value is true which should be false

Comment: So you Just need is three ColView is Scrolled or not right ?

Comment: wait i m updating my answer .

Comment: i have updated my Answer hope you will get your desired result

Answer (score 5):

Scroll view is the superClass of UICollectionView. Just check that scroll view and collection view you are storing are the same instance.

```
if collectionView === scrollView {
}
```

Like this.

Comment: your solution works fine and sorry for not mark your answer as accepted answer, I can only mark one answer as accepted.

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped you.

Comment: Be careful when you compare instances inside `scrollViewDidScroll` during initialize `collectionView` may crash your app